Paradox: E field created by two antennas vs E field created by one antenna with twice the power
I have stumbled into what seems to be a paradox.
Consider a perfect antenna with perfect radiation efficiency and an isotropic radiation pattern. It is fed with a power P. If you consider the E field at a distance d, this E Field I think is proportional to \$\sqrt{P}\$ .
Therefore if I feed it with a power 2P, the E Field is now \$ \sqrt{2P} \$.
If I consider two such antennas each fed with a power P, very close to each other so that the fields add constructively, then the E Field is now the sum of the two E Fields by superposition and the total E field is \$ 2\sqrt{P} \$. It looks like I just won a factor of
\$\sqrt{2}\$ and with N antennas I gain \$\sqrt{N}\$.
This seems to violate energy conservation, where is the mistake? Is it that when I integrate over the whole solid sphere I am bound to have some destructive interference if the antennas are not perfectly superposed and that exactly compensates the gain I found?

In order for the E fields to add, the antennas need to be close, and therefore are coupled.
The 2nd antenna now has to feed its power into both the radiation field, and into the 1st antenna (and vice versa for the 1st w.r.t the 2nd).
There are many ways to consider this, but you could imagine that only ½ the 2nd antenna's power is being radiated, and ½ is going into the 1st (which then effectively only transmits ½ the original power. Thus the total power radiated is the same.
If you arrange the antennas so that the fields don't interact, then you won't have 2*E at each location, just E at more locations, and you will really have 2x the power transmitted.

another more useful way to consider this is that the antenna coupling changes their input impedance, so the power being delivered to them is not what was assumed from the single case
